# Search for files by synchronization status

Tags: sync, onedrive, nextcloud

I can search for file names, types, dates etc. How can I search for non-fully-synchronized (not synchronized to the cloud, not available locally, not always downloaded, each sorted) files in a huge bunch of files and directories (> 50 GB Nextcloud in this case, ideally applicable also to others such as OneDrive; directories integrated in Windows file explorer), other then looking "by eye" for the blue "not synchronized" symbol.

I am looking for sth. like: **list all files (with full path) in this folder and all subfolders, that correspond to the following specific synchronisation state(s)**.

I know I can simply sort a directory for "status", but this does not resolve the problem of the few wanted files spread over hundreds of directories. I simply need to do this task, in whatever way... programmatically, OS-immanent tool, also third-party tool, even if I am not specifically looking for a third party tool.

I would like to check why they are not synchronized fully, and - for complex reasons - need to harmonize directories after (possibly manual) synchronisation/update.

Bonus point: output in a way that can be further processed by drag and drop or easy command line actions.

If possible, I prefer to do this directly on the Windows machine. If substantially easier, WSL or - if outweighing the file transfer - Linux is also accepted.

Comment: I have a similar question. OneDrive has got stuck saying 4 files are processing. I've tried a OneDrive reset and unlinking and relinking but I still see the "4 files are processing" message. I want to find out what those files are!